# How to show 2 instead of 4 products in a row in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.1

How can I show 2 product in a row instead of 4 products in a row in Magento 2.1?

I was trying to show 2 product in a row but not able to do that.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to clear which type of product to show on where.then you can use limit or product_count parameter in your block type content code..